# Yeoman yo command

Tags: yeoman

I've updated my version of Yeoman today to get the stable 1.0 version. When I run the yo command I get the following:

[image]

I was hoping to get this:
[image]

Are these options only available to Mac users?

Answer (score 2):

You don't see the generators in the below screenshots, because you don't have them installed. Just follow the instructions from the "Install a generator" menu entry and install some you like.